# Upgrade old application to use iframe that allows all kind of code

Tags: facebook

I want to upgrade my old application which is created at the time of FBML was in use. So it was built on the basis of FBML & when creating new applications they are created iframe based. So how I can upgrade my old apps which are FBML based to iframe based? Which parameters I need to change? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**DEPRECIATED:** 
refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/568/

---

1. Change app settings from FBML to iFrame in app advanced settings.  Keep in mind not all fbml code will work in canvas and most is being deprecated. **SEE**: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Go to settings / advanced and scroll down to canvas settings.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I do not have such settings

Comment: this image has been depreciated, i do apologize for not updating.  fbml has since been depreciated from the platform all together.